# Mutual foo.bar and bar.foo attributes in django Models with onetooneviews

Tags: django, django-models, relationship, one-to-one

I have two classes, Foo and Bar, in a Django app (on AppEngine if that matters). There's a one to one relationship between them.

```
class Foo(BaseModel):
    bar = Bar.objects.get(foo=self.id)

class Bar(BaseModel):
    foo = models.OneToOneField(Foo, blank=True, null=True, help_text="Foos for this bar")
```

I'd like each object of both classes to have it's related object of the other class as an instance variable.

What's the best way to allow that?

When trying the code above, I'm in an odd situation: since they each refer to each other, I'm trying to use these variables before they're defined (and of course it doesn't work).

I suspect there is A Proper Way to do this, and this isn't it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything. This is the default behaviour. Just define the relationship in `Bar`, and `Foo` will automatically get a `bar` attribute.